# Set dropdown menu's text in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete for my search function.

The source I imported is an array with multiple layers like: country -> city -> street

```
"01": {
    "name": "country",
    "children": {
      "0101": {
        "name": "USA",
        "children": {
          "010101": {
            "name": "New York",
            "children": {
              "010101": {
                "name": "Mandison Street",
                "children": false
              }
            }
          },
          "010102": {
            "name": "Boston",
            "children": {
              "010102": {
                "code_text": "010102",
                "name": "Fanway Street",
                "children": false
              }
            }
          },
          "010103": {
            "name": "Baltimore",
            "children": {
              "010103": {
                "name": "Orange street",
                "children": false
              }
            }
          },
          "010104": {
            "name": "San Francisco",
            "children": {
              "010104": {
                "name": "Sunset street",
                "children": false
              }
            }
          },
          "010105": {
            "name": "Seattle",
            "children": {
              "010105": {
                "name": "Sailor Street,
                "children": false
              }
            }
          },
          "010106": {
            "name": "Houston",
            "children": {
              "010106": {
                "name": "Moon Road",
                "children": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    },
}
```

When I'm searching, the dropdown menu renders:

**counrty > USA > New York > Mandison Street**

**country > USA > Boston > Fanway Street**

But I want the dropdown menu renders street's name only:

**Mandison Street**

**FanWay Street**

Where and how can I realize this appearance?

Thank you!

Comment: The autocomplete `source` option can expect a function with a `resp` parameter, you can manipulate your data to be viewed by street name only, I would have written an answer, But your input will take to much time to write a good answer.

Comment: Please show us your source code, so we get [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)